# how i can add values to my Adress endpoint in wso2 ESB/EI

Tags: proxy, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

i want to add values dynamically to adress endpoint in the proxy in wso2 ESB/EI

```
<address uri="mqtt:/SampleProxy?mqtt.server.host.name=thingsboard.cloud&amp;mqtt.server.port=1883&amp;mqtt.client.id=esb.test.sender&amp;mqtt.topic.name=v1/devices/me/telemetry&amp;mqtt.subscription.qos=0&amp;mqtt.blocking.sender=true&amp;mqtt.subscription.username=25416990;">
```

lets say for exemple i want to add "test" at the end of the endpoint how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a similar problem, but with sending msg to rabbitmq, I created template, where i set *exchangeName* and *routingKey* dynamicaly. In the same manner, you can create your own template. You need to create Header named "To" and using XPATH **concate** interesting address endpoint, and for dynamic values you just use **$func:***{parameter name}*
Something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="rabbitmq.sender">
   <parameter name="exchangeName"/>
   <parameter name="routingKey"/>
   <sequence>
      <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <header name="To"
              scope="default"
              expression="concat('rabbitmq:/?rabbitmq.connection.factory=CachedRabbitMQConnectionFactory&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=',$func:exchangeName,'&amp;rabbitmq.queue.routing.key=',$func:routingKey)"/>
      <send/>
   </sequence>
</template>
```

To use that, call-template mediator is needed. In brackets you can put expression, like below:

```
<call-template target="send.rabbitmq">
    <with-param name="exchangeName" value="test"/>
    <with-param name="routingKey" value="{get-property('testValue')}"/>
</call-template>
```